# how to create a custom application bar in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am developing an application for Windows Phone 7 where i need to create a custom application bar with 5 icons in it. Moreover i want to use this app bar throughout the application without writing the code in all the pages. Please help. I wrote the following codes but didnt work.

```
 public class ApplicationBarCreator
    {
       #region Constructor

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for native page
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="page">Current page</param>
        public ApplicationBarCreator(PhoneApplicationPage page)
        {
            page.ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
            page.ApplicationBar.IsMenuEnabled = true;
            page.ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;

            ApplicationBarMenuItem appBarButtonHome = new ApplicationBarMenuItem("Image/icon_home_select.png");
            appBarButtonHome.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                appBarButtonHome_Click(sender, e, page);
            };
            ApplicationBarMenuItem appBarButtonMap = new ApplicationBarMenuItem("Image/icon_map_deselect.png");
            appBarButtonMap.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                appBarButtonMap_Click(sender, e, page);
            };
            ApplicationBarMenuItem appBarButtonShare = new ApplicationBarMenuItem("Image/icon_share_deselect.png");
            appBarButtonShare.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                appBarButtonShare_Click(sender, e, page);
            };

            page.ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(appBarButtonHome);
            page.ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(appBarButtonMap);
            page.ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(appBarButtonShare);
        }

        private void appBarButtonHome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, PhoneApplicationPage page)
        {
            // doing something
        }

        private void appBarButtonMap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, PhoneApplicationPage page)
        {
            // doing something
        }

        private void appBarButtonShare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, PhoneApplicationPage page)
        {
            // doing something
        }


    }
```

Comment: What happens when you trying to launch the app and use app bar?

Comment: @crea7or There isnt any error and the app bar is not displayed

Comment: @bhaku, do you initialize this manager on page? You should write in your page constructor: ApplicationBarCreator apbCreator = new ApplicationBarCreator(this);